# CSS sticky, table sidebar first column not sticky

Tags: css, fixed, sticky

For a project I need the table head and sidebar (first 6 columns) to be fixed/sticky.

My solution so far works, but not for ever browser (only chrome and edge).
In firefox and safari I have the issue that the first column doesnt stay fixed when sliding to the side and down. Column2 and following stay fixed as they are supposed to.

```css
.sidebar{
position: sticky;
}

.column1{
left:0;
}

.column2{
left: 10vw;
}

.column3{
left: 20vw;
}

.column4{
left: 30vw;
}

.column5{
left: 40vw;
}

.column6{
left: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="th1">1</td>
            <td class="th2">2</td>
            <td class="th3">3</td>
            <td class="th4">4</td>
            <td class="th5">5</td>
            <td class="th6">6</td>
            
            <td> a lot more tds </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="sidebar column1">col 1</td>
            <td class="sidebar column2">col 2</td>
            <td class="sidebar column3">col 3</td>
            <td class="sidebar column4">col 4</td>
            <td class="sidebar column5">col 5</td>
            <td class="sidebar column6">col 6</td>
            
            <td> a lot more tds </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: will you can add the html?

Comment: just edited my post, sorry that its only some basic html code, i cant provide the full code

Comment: Its not very clear but do you mean you want all the numbers(1-6) on your table to be sticky?? navbar sticky also?? but not the column1 to column 6 td?? is this right??

Comment: So the thead (1-6) have to be sticky when scrolling down, and the col 1-6 have to be sticky when scrolling to the side.

Answer (score 1):

`position:sticky;` works fine on most modern browsers as you can see here

https://caniuse.com/?search=Position%20%3Asticky%20

BUT, sticky elements act JUST LIKE relative ones

UNTIll a given position
for example `top:0;`

This is when sticky behaves different than relative

When element's boundary reaches the specified position (top:0) it start to act LIKE a fixed element

So i Think your problem is omitting top or left values however your code is not complete here, you are setting `position:sticky ;` to `.sidebar` which is not used in your HTML...

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Your table and th elements should also have `width` alongside your td elements,

I tried it using `width` and it worked as you described

here's the fiddle link to it

https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/27k9cv6f/3/

Comment: i tried to break my code down to the bear basics for the sticky behavior. you're right the sidebar class was missing in the code sample i provided. since it works perfectly fine for chrome i dont get why its not working for firefox

Comment: well sticky and left are working good in your example, problem is that your ```table``` AND ```th``` AND Also ```td``` elements do not have any width! so they will shrink as much as is necessary to fit the page,, I'll update the answer, check it out and if it was what you want, mark the answer as accepted, Please